# Google OAuth2 client timeout when calling getToken in nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

I was using Google API to do oauth2. The app key Id and secret have been set up, and the URL was created successfully using `oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl`.

```
    let {google} = require('googleapis'),
    contacts = google.people('v1'),
    oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      "MY_KEY",
      "MY_SECRET",
      "http://localhost:8886/mbl/User/ImportContact"
    ),
    scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
    ],
    url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'online',
      scope: scopes
    });
```

In the URL, I authorized the access, and then was redirected to the designated oauthcallback method. The code was in format of

> 4/AADYYeZzY38aKLr1g11IBN2d_9keAdtN2JhDU1WH5pHAPi_0ECfRVS4a-oDiCE5IHPiB3SnyJ4p59ZEFOOSEDFQ#

which looks right.

However, the code execution got stuck at the `oauth2Client.getToken`. It never gets past the following line

```
const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)
```

After a while, it gives me timeout error:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.199.10:443

Could someone kindly help me with it? I have been struggling with it all day.

Answer (score 2):

oAuth2Client.getToken probably returns the desired token in a callback from where you can capture it. You may wish to promisify it before you use async - await with it.

Comment: Thanks @nerdier.js for your answer! Yeah I just tried the callback, and see the error :
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:618:25)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',

Any suggestions how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @Gary Could it be that you're working behind a proxy ? ECONNRESET implies that to me.

Comment: I think you are right, I'm in China, so I need to use VPN to connect to google server. Without VPN, i can't connect to google API to begin with. Not sure if there's a solution. Thanks though :-)